# Use Apply and Replicate in a function for a matrix

Tags: r, apply, replicate

I have a N x N numeric matrix that I converted into a data frame in R, and I need to apply `rnorm` to each cell. However, I want to use `apply` and `replicate` to carry out this calculation. My current code for the calculation in the first cell (that has headers) is:

```r
firstCell <- data.frame(
    rnorm(1000, mean = matrixName[2,1], sd = 0.8*matrixName[2,1])
)
```

I tried using `apply` first with

```
matrixApply <- apply(
    matrixName, c(1,2), function(x) rnorm(
        1000, 
        mean = x, 
        sd = 0.8*x
    )
)
```

Now, I want to use `replicate` to replicate this same calculation 1000 times, resulting in 1000 instances of this N x N matrix. However, when I use the following code, I just get the same matrix, repeated 1000 times.

```
useReplicate <- replicate(n=1000, matrixApply, simplify=F)
```

Comment: What is your desired output? *resulting in 1000 instances of this N x N matrix* ... so a list of data frames? Please show how `matrixName` is defined.

Comment: @Parfait I want a list of 1000 instances of this N x N matrix, which is why I am trying to use replicate. However, when I use my replicate code above, I just get the same matrix repeated 1000 times.

Comment: @Parfait `matrixName` is just a N x N matrix that I converted to a data frame

Comment: I am still unsure of your desired result. What do you mean by *instances*? Right now your `apply` returns a 3-dimensional array of 1000 X N X N. Why is this not your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replicate` repeats an expression.  Once you assign your expression to the object `matrixApply`, replicate doesn't know how `matrixApply` was generated.
You want:

```
useReplicate <- replicate(n=1000, apply(
    matrixName, c(1,2), function(x) rnorm(
        1000, 
        mean = x, 
        sd = 0.8*x
    )
), simplify=F)
```